# ASIHTTPRequest setPostValue iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

I'm accessing a PHP script on a server.
The request URL is like this:

```
 example.com/cgi-bin/getEvent.cgi?EID=19573
```

When I put in the request via a browser, I get back my expected results.

However when I use the ASIHTTP Form request, I'm getting back a result
like the EID isn't being passed via HTTP.

```
NSString *eventID = @"19573";
NSString * const EVENT_URL = @"http://example.com/cgi-bin/getEvent.cgi";

-(void)callWebservice
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:EVENT_URL];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:eventID forKey:@"EID"];
    [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Anyone know of a method to see the full URL being requested?
Or have any clue why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your PHP script is expecting the parameter to be sent on the query string (i.e. as a GET request) rather than as a POST parameter.

If that's the case, you can fix it be sending your request as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?EID=%@",EVENT_URL,eventID]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```